# Accessing an array that is stored in a single cell

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

So, I placed an array `={1,2,3}` in cell(1,1) in a workbook.

How can I assign this to a variable array in VBA say, `dim i() as integer`?

Likewise, how can I take an array in VBA and assign it to a single cell in a worksheet?

Comment: I guess you can do something like a `split` with "," to store into array variable and something similar for vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the array into VBA you can do this:

```
Dim i As Variant
i = Split(Mid(Replace(Cells(1, 1).Formula, "}", ""), 3), ",")
```

And to put the array back:

```
Cells(2, 1).Formula = "={" & Join(i, ",") & "}"
```

Comment: Ahhh replace to rid of brackets ^_^

Comment: @user3089987 This method works for both assigning to VBA and assigning  to the cell. On the first part this is actually pulling the array directly from the cell. Tim's method is RECREATING the array by re-evaluating the cell's formula. That technique can only work in one direction.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you an array directly:

```
Sub TT()

    Dim arr
    arr = Selection.Parent.Evaluate(Selection.Formula) '={1,2,3}

    Debug.Print TypeName(arr)             'Variant()
    Debug.Print LBound(arr), UBound(arr)  '1, 3

End Sub
```

Comment: This works for assigning an array in vba with an array in a cells. Is there a similar method to move an array in VBA to a single worksheet cell, or should I use Excel Hero's answer for that part?

Comment: @user3089987 - yes, it only works one way.  You should use ExcelHero's approach for the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thy these:

```
aArray = Split(rRange, ",")
rRange = Join(aArray, ",")
```

Comment: These are standard VBA functions, so what doesn't work exactly @findwindow?

Comment: Don't remember if it threw an error but intended result did not occur. And if you see @excelhero's answer, you didn't account for brackets. Did you even try your code? XD

Comment: Correct. I just mentioned the functions that can be used

Comment: I see. I will put it in comment next time. Thank you